Is there a scope requirement to "SetWindowPos"?
I'm trying to move a button to the right side of the window on every WM_PAINT message, but SetWindowPos() always returns zero when called in my window procedure (like the docs says when it fails), but not in the WinMain() function.
The docs for the SetWindowPos() function says nothing of this.
Also, I can't find a better word for this other than scope requirement. I tried putting SetWindowPos() into the WinMain() function and it works fine.
my code:
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
    #define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
    #define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");
HWND hwndButton;
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           _T("Code::Blocks Template Windows App"),       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );
    HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
           "BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed
           "OK",      // Button text
           WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles
           0,         // x position
           10,         // y position
           100,        // Button width
           100,        // Button height
           hwnd,     // Parent window
           NULL,       // No menu.
           (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
           NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow (hwndButton, nCmdShow);
    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);

        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                //the code that dont work:
                SetWindowPos(hwndButton,0,500,0,600,600, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);          
            }
        default:
            /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}


There are two variables called hwndButton: One is initialized to the return value of a call to CreateWindow(), the other is declared at global scope and remains zero-initialized for the duration of the program.

In short: The call SetWindowPos(hwndButton, ...) succeeds when hwndButton is a valid window handle and fails when it isn't. The difference between the two call sites is in the set of visible symbols: In WinMain(), hwndButton resolves to the local variable, whereas in WindowProcedure(), hwndButton refers to the global, zero-initialized variable.

i thought if i declared the variable first, and assign a value later inside a function it would work. so the problem is scope? as i thought... thank you very much for the help.

HWND hwndButton =... is not an assignment. It's a value initialization for a brand-new HWND instance. hwndButton = ... is probably what you meant to write.

@Loliconaoquadrado the local hwndButton variable you declared in WinMain is shadowing the global hwndButton variable.  In any case, why are you moving the button inside of WM_PAINT? Don't do that. WM_PAINT is for painting only, not UI management.

@remy i want to have a floating button always at the bottom right side of the window.

The natural way of repositioning controls when resizing their parent is to handle the WM_SIZE/WM_SIZING messages.
